# Why is it better to use event subscribers rather than hooks

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

In drupal 8, we now have the ability to use event subscribers. What's the reason for this? Is it to work with the new cache API better?

Recently I had a task of needing to extract data from a node when it was viewed, but `hook_node_view()` is cached (like nearly everything) in Drupal 8. So I ended up using an event subscriber. Why is using event subscribers a better solution? Is it just that it's more object orientated?

Comment: I can imagine there will come a day when just about everything is an event subscriber. IMO the intent is more clear than alter hooks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see this from two perspectives. First of someone who is looking for a way to communicate with Drupal and so is using the hooks and events that exist. The second one is that of a developer who designs these APIs.

Drupal is in the middle of both, on the one side Drupal is a consumer of the Symfony API, almost every piece of code is placed in Symfony events, and on the other side Drupal provides APIs, in form of legacy hooks or custom Symfony events and other methods like plugins.

You probably didn't use one of the Drupal APIs, more likely a Symfony kernel event, `KernelEvents::REQUEST`. Then you are in the same position as a Drupal developer and this is not a question about hooks or events, because Symfony doesn't provide hooks.

Even if you were using one of the Drupal APIs, you wouldn't have much choice. You would have to select what is provided to you. Only if you design an API in your module to interact with other modules, then you can choose between an event or a hook.

Comment: Yea I see that Symfony doesn't provide hooks but I now have the option to to use hook_node_view, or a Symfony event. But which is preferred and why is what I'm interested in.

Comment: This depends on where you want to hook in. If you know exactly where this should be most times you have no choice, you have to take what the API is offering you. A discussion of the preferred method only makes sense if you design an API.

Comment: In that case I really don't see the point of leaving such hooks in if drupal 8, I'd like to understand why hooks like the ones we are talking about are still available in 8 when there really doesn't seem much point to them.

Comment: To make life easier for people coming from D7?

Comment: Yea that makes sense, but hook_node_view gets cached. Which I think renders it really limited in use cases. So maybe in 9 we'll completely remove legacy hooks. Interesting conversation, thanks.

Comment: If hook_node_view will be converted to an event trigger in D9, this will have no effect on caching. You still need to use a kernel event with a high priority to get your code called before the drupal caching event subscribers, which are listening to the same kernel event.

Comment: @Kevinhowbrook Further reading: https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/alter-or-dispatch-drupal-8-events-versus-alter-hooks

Comment: @4k4, I think I was really just a bit perplexed because using hook_node_view in d8 seems a bit useless when you can specify the priority for the kernal event. Or maybe I have not yet seen a way to specify the priority when using hook_node_view, and if you can do that, then that's just duplicate methods that really shouldn't be there.

Comment: This is not a duplicate method, both are completely different places to hook into Drupal. If you want to have priority over a kernel event subscriber, eg DynamicPageCacheSubscriber, then you need to subscribe to the same kernel event and use a higher priority. The hook here is in the early stages of the render pipeline of an entity. This is not called again, like any other code involved, when the rendered result is delivered from cache.

Comment: So really, I don't see a use for hook_node_view anymore, unless I didn't want priority over a Kernel event (not come across that requirement yet). Your responses are really useful, thanks for your input.

Comment: In this hook you can change the result of the different field formatters before the entity build is forwarded to the theming level. BTW the hooks in theming like preprocess are also not called again when delivered from cache. Then you would need to remove them as well.